# How to infer that $\|T\| \leq \sqrt{B}$ from the fact that $\left\{f_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a Bessel sequence ($T$ is the pre-frame operator)?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\left\{f_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{H}$ and $B>0$ be given. Then if $\left\{f_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a Bessel sequence with Bessel bound $B$ then the operator
$$
T:\left\{c_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty} \rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k f_k
$$
is a well-defined bounded operator from $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ into $\mathcal{H}$ and $\|T\| \leq \sqrt{B}$.

Don't focus on the part concerning that $T$ is a well-defined bounded operator (we can find it e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858051/bessel-sequence-and-synthesis-operator)), but consider instead the claim $\|T\| \leq \sqrt{B}$. I know that
\begin{aligned}
\left\| T\left\{c_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty} \right\| &=\sup _{\|g\|=1}\left|\left\langle T\left\{c_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty},g\right\rangle\right| \\
&=\sup _{\|g\|=1}\left|\left\langle\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k f_k, g\right\rangle\right|\\
& \leq \sup _{\|g\|=1} \sum_{k=1}^\infty\left|c_k\left\langle f_k, g\right\rangle\right| \\
& \leq\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left|c_k\right|^2\right)^{1 / 2} \sup _{\|g\|=1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left|\left\langle f_k, g\right\rangle\right|^2\right)^{1 / 2} \\
& \leq \sqrt{B}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left|c_k\right|^2\right)^{1 / 2} .
\end{aligned}
The question is, why from this we can infer that $\|T\| \leq \sqrt{B}$?

Comment: You know that $\|T(c_k)\|_{H} \le \sqrt{B} \|c_k\|_{l^2}$ for all $(c_k) \in l^2$. So $\|T\| \le \sqrt{B}$ by the definition of the operator norm.

Comment: Oh, I got it, thank you!